# Vue.js "$slots.default()[0].el" is null when passing dynamic slot with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to access HTMLElement of dynamic slot that passed by v-for
but el is always empty

**app.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <prod>
       <span>
         <div  v-for="item in items">{{item.title}}</div>
       </span>
    </prod>
  </div>
</template>
.
.
.
data: () => {
    return { items: [{ title: '1' }, { title: '2' }] };
  }
```

**prod.vue** :

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
.
.

  mounted() {
    
       console.log(this.$slots.default()[0].el);
  }
.
.
```

but el is always null
but when I pass it hardcoded like below el is available

```
<prod>
   <span>
     <div>a</div><div>b</div>
   </span>
</prod>
```

I mean how I can access HTMLElement of dynamic slot ?

Answer (score 2):

its look like there is no solution for this
But
we can use refs

```
<div ref="main">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
.
.
// and we can access the dom with :
this.$refs.main
```

also there is [updated](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated) method that you can monitor changes of slots